# Installing Gnome 3.8 on Ubuntu 13.04 fails

Tags: gnome, 13.04

I just followed these instructions http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/ope...on-ubuntu/4343 on a fresh installed Ubuntu 13.04 and it crashed during installation with the following error message:

Code:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-25-generic
cp: cannot stat ‘/module-files.d/libpango1.0-0.modules’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/modules/pango-basic-fc.so’: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-25-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ca-certificates ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
done.
done.
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea what this is?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your problem is to do with dependencies or not, but if you install something with `dpkg` and it fails due to dependencies run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will complete the failed install and install the required packages.

I learned this from a 26k user the other day when I incorrectly advised someone to do it a very long winded way.

Comment: ahh interesting. so instead of `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop` i do `sudo apt-get install -f gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop` ?

Comment: after a `dpkg` has failed, just `sudo apt-get install -f` should fix it. The -f option is Force.

Comment: if you installed with apt-get and it failed with dependency issues,  `sudo apt-get build-dep <package>` should sort it out